# $\mathbb{Q}$ can not be embedded in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: general-topology, rational-numbers, integers

> Show that $\mathbb{Q}$ can not be embedded in $\mathbb{Z}$ (where both has the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}$)

**My attempt at a solution**

Since Z is discrete, {k} is open in $\mathbb{Z}$ with subspace topology. Since f is continious $f^{−1} ( \lbrace k \rbrace )$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$. $\mathbb{Q}$ has no isolated points. So $f^{−1} ( \lbrace k \rbrace )$ not singleton and not finite . I must show that there is not a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{Q}$ with $\mathbb{f(Q)}$

Comment: A continuous map $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is called a (topological) embedding if the map $f':X \rightarrow f(X)$
 obtained by restricting the range of f is homeomorphism (Here $f(X)$ has the subspace topology)

Comment: You probably meant to write "homeomorphism".

Comment: What do you know about the topologies on $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ induced by the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: There is a deleted answer that brightened my afternoon.

Comment: Z is discrete while Q has no isolated points. So $f^{−1} [{k}]$ not singleton and not finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Z is discrete (meaning that every subset is open), {k} is open in $\mathbb{Z}$. Since f is continious $f^{−1} ( \lbrace k \rbrace )$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$.

$\mathbb{Q}$ has no isolated points (meaning that no singleton set is open; in fact, no finite set is open). So $f^{−1} ( \lbrace k \rbrace )$ not singleton and not finite .

Any homeomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}$  to $\mathbb{f(Q)}$ would have to be a bijection and so the preimage of the singleton $ \lbrace k \rbrace$ in $\mathbb{Z}$(which is open) would have to be a singleton in $\mathbb{Q}$. It is a contradiction.

Hence $\mathbb{Q}$ can not be embedded in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: suppose $f\colon {\bf Q}\to {\bf Z}$ is continuous, and $k$ is in the range of $f$. What can you say about $f^{-1}[\{k\}]$?

Comment: @NicolA: What else?

Comment: Z is discrete  while Q has no isolated points

Comment: So $f^{-1} [k]$ not singleton and not finite ?

Comment: Any homeomorphism from $\mathbb {Q}$ to $f(\mathbb {Q})$ would have to be a bijection and so the preimage of the singleton {k} in $\mathbb {Z}$ (which is open) would have to be a singleton in $\mathbb {Q}$

Comment: it is a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: So we obtain $\mathbb{Q}$ cannot be embedded in $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: And as you have probably noticed, a more general statement is that if $X$ has no isolated points, then it does not embed in a discrete space.